# How to test QnA knowledge base with fiddler

Tags: azure, botframework, azure-qna-maker

I just created a qna knowledge base but i'm finding it difficult to consume the endpoint api. I have actually done this before Microsoft changed the endpoint configuration features. please find below my test credentials

```
POST /knowledgebases/6a523867-3606-480e-9179-bd7e06df4b4d/generateAnswer
Host: https://kb12.azurewebsites.net/qnamaker
Authorization: EndpointKey 604c416d-ef24-402d-b889-cbbb4c16a396
Content-Type: application/json
{"question":"hi"}
```

i used `Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: 604c416d-ef24-402d-b889-cbbb4c16a396 but i keep getting 502 error
.

Comment: If this isn't a public knowledge base, please remove the key from the text above.

Comment: its a public knowledge base

Comment: i just need  a solution to the qna v4.0 issue

Comment: **how do i get answer to question through the API????**

Comment: Hi @OluwatosinSamuelBabalola, you can use postman to make request to the API. Or add **tls1.2**, for details, please refer to my reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> keep getting 502 error

I do a test using fiddler and can reproduce same issue, to solve the issue, you can go **Tools > Options > HTTPS** to make **tls1.2** allowable.

[image]

***Test result:***

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Curl example that works for me -

replace xxxx..., yyyy...., and myazureresourcename with your own values shown on the publish page.

```
curl \
--header "Content-type: application/json" \
--header "Authorization: EndpointKey xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx" \
--request POST \
--data '{"question":"what is my endpoint?"}' \
https://myazureresourcename.azurewebsites.net/qnamaker/knowledgebases/yyyyyyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyyyyyyyyyy/generateAnswer
```